# cURL - multi - too much open sockets

Tags: c++, curl

I have problem with cURL. I have used `curl_multi` with enabled pipelining (server support it). But I have over 10000 single URLs, I need to download. I dont have that many free sockets. How to handle this ?

I have read about  `curl_multi_socket_action`, but I can not find some simple example, or how to modify my code

```
CURLM * curlm = curl_multi_init();

curl_multi_setopt(curlm, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 3);
curl_multi_setopt(curlm, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, 1);

std::vector<CURL_WRITE *> ptrArray;

std::map<MyStringAnsi, MyStringAnsi>::const_iterator it;
for (it = data[0].begin(); it != data[0].end(); it++)
{
    CURL_WRITE * curlData = new CURL_WRITE;
    curlData->dataIndex = &(it->first);
    curlData->threadID = 0;


    CURL * curl = InitSingleCURL(it->first, curlData);          
    curl_multi_add_handle(curlm, curl);

    ptrArray.push_back(curlData);
    curls.push_back(curl);
}


int still_running = 0;
/* lets start the fetch */
do 
{

    while(curl_multi_perform(curlm, &still_running) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    #ifdef _WIN32
     Sleep(10);
    #else
     usleep(10);
    #endif
 } while (still_running);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't really explain much which makes answering really hard. The multi interface doesn't force you to do all transfers at once.

[CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_setopt.html#CURLMOPTMAXTOTALCONNECTIONS) is probably what you want, added in libcurl 7.30.0.